# How to retrieve tag value using junit.jupiter?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I am trying to retrieve the tag value using junit5. Is there any way to retrieve below tag value ABC, PQR, XYZ, MNQ in the beforeEach method using Junit5?

```
 @WIP
 @SMOKE
 @PENDING

 @Tags(value = {@Tag("ABC"),@Tag("PQR"),@Tag("XYZ"), @Tag("MNQ"))})
 public void TestMethod() {
       Launch()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by declaring `org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInfo` as a method parameter of your `@BeforeEach` method.

```
public class TestTest {

    @BeforeEach
    public void before(TestInfo testInfo) {
        System.out.println(testInfo.getTags());
    }

    @Test
    @Tags(value = {@Tag("ABC"), @Tag("PQR"), @Tag("XYZ"), @Tag("MNQ")})
    public void TestMethod() {
    }
}
```

Prints out

```
[ABC, PQR, XYZ, MNQ]
```

Comment: I have tried that but its also prints [WIP, SMOKE ,PENDING, ABC, PQR , XYZ, MNQ]

Comment: Maybe your class has tags which are added into this set

Comment: Is there any way to exclude these tags from my test? basically, all these tags are associated with my test.  I want only [ABC, PQR, XYZ, MNQ] which is part of  @Tags(value = {@Tag("ABC"), @Tag("PQR"), @Tag("XYZ"), @Tag("MNQ")})

Comment: testInfo.getTestMethod() gives you access to the Method object, on which you can then use Java‘s reflection for retrieving tag annotations. That said, Jupiter implies that tags are „inherited“ from the class to its methods. Breaking that semantics will confuse the standard user.