# How to retrieve value from custom junit 5 tags using java?

Tags: java, junit5

I am trying to retrieve value from a custom Junit 5 tag but facing issue while retrieving value of TestCaseDetails tag.

```
@Test
@Tags(value ={@Tag("TT"), @Tag("MM")})
@TestCaseDetails(Id="1234")
@MongoDataSet(value = "/dataset/SampleTestData.json", cleanAfter = true, cleanBefore = true)
```

**TestCaseDetails.class**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Tag("api") @Tag("identifier")
@Test
public @interface TestCaseDetails {
 String Id();
}
```

I want to print  1234 value associated with the TestCaseDetails tag.

**What I have tried:**

```
   class JUnit5ExampleTest {


    @Test
    @Tags(value ={@Tag("TT"), @Tag("MM")})
    @TestCaseDetails(testcaseId="1234")
    @MongoDataSet(value = "/dataset/SampleTestData.json", cleanAfter = true, cleanBefore = true)
    void multipleTags() throws Exception {

       System.out.println("*******************JUnit5ExampleTest********************************");
   //Solution 1:     
   Method[] methods = JUnit5ExampleTest.class.getMethods();
        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.isAnnotationPresent(TestCaseDetails.class)) {
                TestCaseDetails ta = m.getAnnotation(TestCaseDetails.class);
                System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%"+ta.Id());
            }
        }

  //Solution 2:      
    JUnit5ExampleTest ob=new JUnit5ExampleTest();
        try {
            Class c = ob.getClass();

            Method m = c.getMethod("multipleTags");

            TestCaseDetails anno = m.getAnnotation(TestCaseDetails.class);

            System.out.println(anno.Id() );
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException exc) {
            System.out.println("Method Not Found.");
        }
    }
}
```

**don't want to use below solution:**

- [How to retrieve tag value using junit.jupiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67788265/how-to-retrieve-tag-value-using-junit-jupiter)

Comment: (I did not vote negative but) full reproducible example you want to do please (you want read an annotation in runtime? you want configure a class or global tests and extend with custom settings? ...)

Comment: Do you know what a [`TestInfo`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInfo.html) can do in JUnit 5? It has a method `getTags()`... Ok, you don't want it...

Comment: @josejuan : thank you for reply, I have added tried solution but its not working atm.

Comment: @deHaar: thank you for reply, Yes I know TestInfo but don't want to use it.

Comment: What's the reason you don't want to use `TestInfo`?  Is it because you don't want to add parameters to test methods?  Would writing a JUnit extension be an option if this is the case?

Comment: TestInfo as a parameter can be used in normal test methods as well as lifecycle methods such as before/after.

Comment: Any working solution ref do you have?

Comment: Also I have tried to print tag using System.out.println(testInfo.getTags()); : Its giving me below info[TT, MM, api, identifier, antkorwin-mongodb-testcontainers]

Comment: `TestInfo.getTags()` will only retrieve `@Tag` values and won't know anything about custom annotations.  For retrieving custom annotations, grab the `Method` of the test using `getTestMethod()` and then use the Java reflection API to read annotations from the method using something like `getAnnotation()`.

Answer (score 0):

If `TestInfo` is an option, it can be used as a parameter to test methods.

```
public class TestMeta
{
    @Test
    @TestCaseDetails(id = "g1")
    void test(TestInfo info)
    {
        //Retrieve test case details annotation for this test
        Optional<TestCaseDetails> testCaseDetails = info.getTestMethod().flatMap(m -> Optional.ofNullable(m.getAnnotation(TestCaseDetails.class)));
        testCaseDetails.ifPresent(caseDetails -> System.out.println("Test case: " + caseDetails.id()));

        //Remaining test code...
    }
}
```

---

This might be fine if it is only needed on one test, but it can also be put into an extension for reusability:

```
public class TestCaseDetailsPrinter implements BeforeTestExecutionCallback
{
    @Override
    public void beforeTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception
    {
        context.getElement()
               .flatMap(m -> Optional.ofNullable(m.getAnnotation(TestCaseDetails.class)))
               .ifPresent(testCaseDetails -> System.out.println("Test case: " + testCaseDetails.id()));
    }
}
```

and used like this:

```
@ExtendWith(TestCaseDetailsPrinter.class)
public class TestMeta2
{
    @Test
    @TestCaseDetails(id = "g2")
    void test()
    {
        //Remaining test code
    }
}
```

The key part to both of these approaches is to get access to the `Method` object of the test, which can then be queried via reflection (using `getAnnotation()`) to read annotations that are present on that method.

Comment: I don't want to use TestInfo with my  multipleTags()  method